# Problems with my new lens on my Nikkon D3000

Tags: lens, nikon

I just added a new 70-300 Nikkor lens to my Nikkon D3000 camera. It will not auto focus or take a picture with the new lens. It seems to be installed properly and is communicating with my camera. It just does not allow me to take a picture. I can put the old 55mm lens on and it works fine. Help!

Comment: _Which_ Nikon 70-300mm lens? There are several.

Comment: Nikon have made quite a few 70-300mm lenses over the years - some will & some won't work on a D3000 - so you'll have to tell us exactly which one you got.

Comment: Although the lenses and camera models are different, the core issue is the same: Nikon's AF-P lens series has limited or no compatibility with any but the latest models of DX bodies.

Comment: See also: [Why won't my 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G auto-focus on my Nikon D3200?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88395/15871)

Comment: And: [Extendable Nikon 18-55 mm lenses compatible with D7100?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/84700/15871)

Answer (score 4):

If your lens is the [Nikkor AF-P 70-300mm f/4.5-5.6E ED VR](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-p-nikkor-70-300mm-f%252f4.5-5.6e-ed-vr.html) lens, it is not compatible with the D3000. From Nikon's product page:

> The number of cameras compatible with this lens is limited. Even for compatible cameras, a firmware update may be required. Fully compatible models: D7500, D5600, D3400, D500.
>
> Fully compatible models (without limitations) after available firmware update: D5, D750, D610, D600, D5500, D5300, D3300. Download firmware updates at: http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/index.html
>
> Regardless of firmware update, these models will still have some limitations*: D4, D4S, D3, D3X, D3S, D810, D810A, D800, D800E, Df, D700, D300, D300S, D7200, D7100, D7000, D5200.
>
> *Because these models reset focus when reverting from standby status (timer off), pre-focus shooting is not available.
>
> **Incompatible models**: D2 series, D1 series, D200, D100, D90, D80, D70 series, D60, D50, D40 series, D5100, D5000, D3200, D3100, **D3000**, film SLR cameras.

This is true of all AF-P lenses in Nikon's lineup, the first of which was introduced in 2016. The AF-P motor system requires lens focus feedback (and possibly power delivery) that older camera body designs and/or firmware were not capable of providing.